# backbone.js (underscore template) append masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, jquery-masonry

I would like to append new views to my existing **masonry list**.
Why does my view not append? Am I missing something?

[Masonry.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

**function:**

```
render_masonry_append: function() {
             var self = this;
            _(this.collection_append.models).each(function(item) {
                var view = new Home_thumbnail_view({
                    model: item.attributes
                });
                //console.log(view);
                $mainListContainer.append(view.render()).masonry("appended", view.render());
            });
            console.log($mainListContainer);
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `view.render()` returns `this`, and then change that line to:

```
$mainListContainer.append(view.render().el).masonry("appended", view.render().el);
```

I'm not sure what `masonry()` does, so I added `view.render().el` there too, but that's your call.  Most likely you don't need to be render()ing the view twice, so maybe even better would be:

```
view.render();
$mainListContainer.append(view.el).masonry("appended", view.el);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I forgot `.el`. It works, I can accept your answer in 4 mins. Thanks!

Comment: Np :)  I would appreciate that!